# C++ function without return returning data

Tags: c++, class, object

Sorry,

I was playing with c++ and i did something strange and it worked, someone knows why it worked.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "c1.h"

using namespace std;

Classe c(){
    Classe v();
}
int main(){
    cout << c().x;
    return 0;
}
```

c1.h

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Classe{

    public:
        Classe(){
            x = 100;;
    }
    int x;
    };
```

So, why i can call c().x if the function Classe c(){Classe v()} dont return the variable?

No warnings with and without -wall.

if i do return v on the function it dont compile:
Error message with return:

main.cpp: In function ‘Classe c()’:
main.cpp:8: error: conversion from ‘Classe (*)()’ to non-scalar type ‘Classe’ requested

Comment: Try compiling with warnings enabled. `-wall` on gcc would show you a big fat warning about not returning a value from `c`.

Comment: but question about 'how does this function work?' (without 'return' it pass through function and create the object)

Comment: Okay, but how i can access the variable x if it dont return the value

Comment: With `-wall`, I get error: unrecognized option ‘-wall’, with `-Wall` I get `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void`.

Comment: you declare function, which return `Classe` object. so, in defaults, the compiler passed through this function and 'create' the object of your class. 
so, your function was inserted into funcion_table with signature 'i return object `Classe`'. after `c()` compiler saw returning value of function in function_table and saw `Classe`

Comment: `-Wall` is not -W _all_, really. Better use `-Wall -Wpedantic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that is by accident,  your compiler should have warned you that c() does not return a value.

accidentally the register used to return a value from a function happened to be loaded with the address of the local variable allocated within that function.

And, btw, your declaration of local v() in the function c()  does not declare a variable of type `Classe`, but a function taking no arguments, returning an object of `Classe`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't necessarily know that `c` doesn't return a valid object (it could be defined far away from `main`). You'll get a compiler warning when compiling `c` though.